# Get text of TextView from a row of ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview, row

I have a layout for a row of LIstView items like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="40sp" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"  />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_btn"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="share"
            android:onClick="myClickHandler" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And i want to get the text of TextView when user click on delete button(in myClickHandler() method),

with this code:

```
RelativeLayout vwParentRow = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
```

I get the parent of Button(RelativeLayout), but don't know how to get the text of TextView that in parent of parent of Button

How i can to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in `myClickHandler()` method

```
RelativeLayout vwParentRow = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
LinearLayout vwGrandParentRow = (LinearLayout)vwParentRow.getParent();

TextView yourTV=(TextView)vwGrandParentRow.findViewByid(R.id.label);

Log.i("Text",yourTV.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextView.getText().toString()

Comment: yes thats the way to get text from Textview. And using getParent you can reach to your textview as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView )v.getParent().getParent().findViewById(R.id.label)
String yourText = yourTextView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: i get this Error:The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ViewParent

Answer (score 0):

> It should working

```
  TextView textviewDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
  String selectedText=textviewDate.getText().toString();
```